# Fill one Dataframe Column from specific value in list of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

My dataframe has a column `pairs` that contains a key-pair `list`. Each key is unique in the list. e.g:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id':  ['1', '2', '3'],
        'abc':None,
        'pairs': [ ['abc/123', 'foo/345', 'xyz/789'],  ['abc/456', 'foo/111', 'xyz/789'],  ['xxx/222', 'foo/555', 'xyz/333'] ]
      })
```

**Dataframe is**:

```
  id | abc  | pairs
  ------------------------------------
  1  |None  | [abc/123, foo/345, xyz/789]
  2  |None  | [abc/456, foo/111, xyz/789]
  3  |None  | [xxx/222, foo/555, xyz/333]
```

The column `abc` is filled with the value in column `pairs` if an element (idx=0) split by `\` has the value (key) =='abc'.

**Expected** `df`:

```
  id | abc  | pairs
  ------------------------------------
  1  |123   | [abc/123, foo/345, xyz/789]
  2  |456   | [abc/456, foo/111, xyz/789]
  3  |None  | [xxx/222, foo/555, xyz/333]
```

I look for something like:

```
df.loc[df['pairs'].map(lambda x: 'abc' in (l.split('/')[0] for l in x)), 'abc'] = 'FOUND'
```

my problem is to replace the *FOUND* by the correct value the `l.split('/')[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
# data
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id':  ['1', '2', '3'],
        'abc':None,
        'pairs': [ ['abc/123', 'foo/345', 'xyz/789'],  ['abc/456', 'foo/111', 'xyz/789'],  ['xxx/222', 'foo/555', 'xyz/333'] ]
      })
# construct a dict in loop and get value of abc key
df['abc'] = df['pairs'].apply(lambda x: dict(e.split('/') for e in x).get('abc'))
df
```

Upon reading the question again, it seems you're only interested in `abc` key if it's the first element in the lists, so instead of reading each list, just index the first element and split

```py
df['abc'] = df['pairs'].apply(lambda x: dict([x[0].split('/')]).get('abc'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.str` repeatedly:

```
df['abc'] = df['pairs'].str[0].str.split('/').loc[lambda x: x.str[0] == 'abc'].str[1]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  id  abc                        pairs
0  1  123  [abc/123, foo/345, xyz/789]
1  2  456  [abc/456, foo/111, xyz/789]
2  3  NaN  [xxx/222, foo/555, xyz/333]
```

More readable alternative:

```
x = df['pairs'].str[0].str.split('/')
df.loc[x.str[0] == 'abc', 'abc'] = x.str[1]
```

Comment: "*You can use .str repeatedly*" -> yes, but [not for performance ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72504954/16343464)

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.get` as much as you like ;)

```
s = df['pairs'].str.get(0).str.split('/')
df['abc'] = np.where(s.str.get(0) == 'abc', s.str.get(1), None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try, you don't need `apply` nor lambda functions:

```
a = df['pairs'].str[0].str
df['abc'] = a.split('/').str[1].where(a.startswith('abc'))
```

Output:

```
  id  abc                        pairs
0  1  123  [abc/123, foo/345, xyz/789]
1  2  456  [abc/456, foo/111, xyz/789]
2  3  NaN  [xxx/222, foo/555, xyz/333]
```

Note:  str[0] is equal to using str.get(0).

["Elements in the split lists can be accessed using get or [] notation:"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings)

Answer (score 0):

"*You can use .str repeatedly*" -> Yes, but… **it is quite slow**!

In this context, it is much better to use a list comprehension:

```
df['abc'] = [x[1] if (x:=l[0].split('/'))[0].startswith('abc') else float('nan')
            for l in df['pairs']]
```

**Rule of thumb: if you need 3 `str` or more, better try the list comprehension!**

One picture is better than thousand words: test of the performance (all current answers) from 3 to almost 1M rows:

[image]

###### bonus: matching first "abc" on any position (not only 1st)

```
df['abc'] = [next((x.split('/')[1] for x in l if x.startswith('abc')), None)
             for l in df['pairs']]
```